# Sum of a series with

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to compute the sum of the following series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{n-1}\sin^{3}\left(a \over \,3^{n}\right)
$$
The series is clearly convergent by the ratio test, as well as by comparison with $(\frac{a}{3^n})^3$. If I take the derivative with respect to $a$, I am eventually left with $\cos(\frac{a}{3^n})-\cos^3(\frac{a}{3^n})$, which doesn't seem very helpful, plus I'm not sure it's okay to take the derivative. Multiplying by sine functions to try to get a telescopical sum didn't lead me anywhere. Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a hint:$$\sin(3x)=3\sin x-4\sin^3x \to \color{red}{\sin^3(x)=\frac14\Big(3\sin x-\sin(3x)\Big)}$$so
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{n-1}\sin ^3{\frac{a}{3^n}}=\\
\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{n-1}(3\sin {\frac{a}{3^n}}-\sin {\frac{3a}{3^n}})=\\
\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty (3^n\sin {\frac{a}{3^n}}-3^{n-1}\sin {\frac{a}{3^{n-1}}})=\\
\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty (f(n)-f(n-1))$$

Comment: Oh, okay, I see. Thanks for the help, I'll accept your answer!

Comment: @Wolfuryo: your welcome, Can you take over now ?

Comment: Yes, should I propose an edit to your post with the full solution?

Comment: @Wolfuryo:No, take it easy.

Comment: woah easy peasy lemon-squeezy (+1)